# Nginx rewrite address does not automatically add parameters

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Original request address:

```
www.example.com/index.php?r=mobile/receive/index
```

Rewritten request address:

```
www.example2.com/newindex.php?r=mobile2/receive2/index2
```

Here is my own configuration:

```
if ($args ~* "^r=mobile/receive/index") {
    rewrite ^ "http://www.example2.com/newindex.php?r=mobile2/receive2/index2";
}
```

But the end of the rewritten address is like this:

```
http://www.example2.com/index.php?r=mobile2/receive2/index2&r=mobile/receive/index
```

Do you see my problem? The rewritten address is automatically added, but this is not what I want. The same parameter keys will result in the back cover front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the original query string being appended to the target URL you need to include an additional question mark (`?`) at the end of the rewritten URL. For example:

```
rewrite ^ http://www.example2.com/newindex.php?r=mobile2/receive2/index2?;
```

Reference:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: Ask, if I have a part of the parameters and need to add it? Not like now, all of which are not attached?

Comment: If you need to merge just one or two parameters then it gets more complex... You can have a capturing group (ie. parenthesised sub pattern) in your conditional regex and use a backreference (`$1`..`$9`) in the URL replacement string to insert the matched sub pattern in the target URL.